# Facebook SDK for iOS: Where is the wizard?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Trying to follow Facebook's instructions for adding the iOS SDK but they lost me at step 1.

[image]

The download is a zip file containing the following:

[image]

Anyone have any idea where this wizard is?

Comment: save it anywhere .Mainly in documents folder.Why do u need wizard?

Comment: Cause it says `wizard` in the instructions and I'm too much of a noob to start screwing around with unknown files.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is nothing related with the wizard. Now you have the SDK containing the required framework. Now simply use those frameworks in your project. For further help follow "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started".